# CSS floatimages side by side

Tags: css-float

I can't get my images to go side my side (below share and follow) on this page:

http://toddheymandirector.com/REEL/index_newlook_gallery2222.html

The suspect code:

```
#gallery ul div {
  min-width:26.6%;
  margin:0;
  float:left
  background-color:#595959;
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: it didn't workhttp://toddheymandirector.com/REEL/index_newlook_gallery2222aa.html

Answer (score 0):

find this block into your css file:

```
img.a {
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 10;
}
```

and replace the position to relative:

```
img.a {
    left: 0;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 10;
}
```

Comment: thanks though  it didn't work http://toddheymandirector.com/REEL/index_newlook_gallery2222aa.html  though it almost did -- it stopped them from stacking but they're bouncing now

Comment: sorry i thought i edited this.. it worked!! thank you toddheymandirector.com/REEL/index_newlook_gallery2222aa.html  do you know how to get the social div (Facebook google plus buttons) do always be below the thumbs no matter how its resized? i tried margins.. right now the thumbs cover it if they go to the next line